# Formulas make SpreadsheetApp work slower in Google Sheets Script

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-sheets-formula

This problem appeared recently ~August 25, 2022.

My `onEdit` trigger relies on a sheet name and the script runs too long to get it. This is the smallest script to reproduce an error in my enviroment:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var t = new Date();
  console.log('we are in onEdit!');
  var sheetName = e.range.getSheet().getName();
  console.log(sheetName);
  console.log('We got sheet name. Time past = ' + (new Date() - t));
}
```

The function `range.getName()` works too slow, and the script is timed out.

I did not see this behavior any time before. Other sample: `SpreadsheetApp`. In my other file this line takes 30 sec.:

`SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);`

### Reproduce the error

Here's the file with minimal code needed to reproduce the error:

[onEdit Crash Test ➡️ e.range.getSheet().getName()](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TjQ2u9u3fqH6296jehNqIn_Q0-MwTU7-K-EsyS26IcU/edit#gid=0)

Please make a copy.

To Reproduce the `onEdit` Error

1. Print 1 in the first cell
2. Immediately press enter and Print 2
3. Repeat it a few times
4. Go to the script editor and see execution time

[Original](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FVg-IBLTWhZJzRSivogCLexP2z2oorH-pg1LITjtduE/edit#gid=355455400)

It has a few formulas and the script works fast.

My goal is to understand why formulas cause `sheet.getName()` method to slow down.

### Error

> Exceeded maximum execution time

The max. time for onEdit is 30 sec. Tests showed that `sheet.getName()` worked too long. I cannot see the edited sheet name without the `getName()` function as it is inside a trigger.

### My Fix

Even Lock and Cache did not resolve this:

**Injection**

```
  /**  Injection. Use Cache to Speed Up `getName()` method */ 
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  try {
    lock.waitLock(30000); // wait 30 seconds for others'
  } catch (e) {
    throw 'Could not get Sheet Name in 30 sec. :(';
  } 
  var sheetNameCacheKey = 'sheetNameforThoseWhoForgotten';
  var c = CacheService.getUserCache();
  var sheetNameFromCache = c.get(sheetNameCacheKey);
  if (sheetNameFromCache) {
    sets.sheetName = sheetNameFromCache;  
    console.log('Prolongated Cache Life!');
    c.put(sheetNameCacheKey, sets.sheetName, 5);
  } else {
    // This function is actually needed, 
    // but does not work fast
    //               ⏳
    sets.sheetName = sets.sheet.getName(); 
    // Write Sheet Name to Memory for 5 seconds
    c.put(sheetNameCacheKey, sets.sheetName, 5);
    console.log('Added Sheet Name to Cache!');
  }
  lock.releaseLock();
  /**  End of Injection */
```

This code makes my trigger more stable, but it still fails occasionally.

### Speed Tests

> time to read sheet name is: 151766

This is almost 3 minutes! But this number changes and occasionally it may take ~150 ms to run.

### Notes

My guess is this error caused by the latest big update and new functions for Google Sheets:

- https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2022/08/named-functions-google-sheets.html

I think so because this problem comes in hand with `IMPORTRANGE` error:

> Import Range internal error.

Comment: You show an onEdit(e) function that is not in your spreadsheet script editor.  Have you replaced the one in the spreadsheet with the one you are showing above?  Or do you have 2 onEdit(e) functions in your spreadsheet?

Comment: Then I guess I don't understand the question.  Your onEdit() in the spreadsheet does a lot of "stuff"  through `onEdit_DVL_(e)` so what exactly is causing the problem?

Comment: If I replace your onEdit(e) with the one shown about it takes 1.6sec to execute.  So again I don't know what the issue is.  Plus you are missing a closing parenthesis in your shown script.

Comment: @TheWizEd thanks, closing parenthesis - added. As my Sample Script is not relevant to the problem I've deleted the link from the description. Also updated the description. Hope it is clear now. I guess you do not believe me and cannot understand the error because I could not get the file to reproduce the error. For now I still could not make dummy file so you could test it

Comment: @TheWizEd I've finally added a sample file with lots of formulas and it reproduces the error. Please see the update

Comment: How frequently does this happen? I have tested the shared doc and with 5+ changes at the same time it did work without an issue.

Comment: Thanks for tests @Kessy, I cannot predict this, as it may differ depending on your enviroment. For now I've been able to reproduce the file with minimal code to test: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TjQ2u9u3fqH6296jehNqIn_Q0-MwTU7-K-EsyS26IcU/edit#gid=0. Please see it.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether my workaround is useful for your situation, I proposed a workaround. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Issue and workaround:

I have experienced the same situation as you. It seems that when the large calculations by the formulas are included in the Spreadsheet, such a situation occurs. In this case, this is also reflected in the trigger and the direct execution of the script. I'm not sure whether this situation is the current specification or a bug.

At that time, I noticed that there are differences in process costs for the methods of Google Apps Script under this condition. For example, when I saw your provided script in your sample Spreadsheet, I found the following script.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var t = new Date();
  console.log('we are in onEdit!');
  var sheetName = e.range.getSheet().getName(); // times out ⏳!
  console.log(sheetName);
  console.log('We got sheet name. Time past = ' + (new Date() - t));
}
```

When this script is used as a sample, in this case, the process cost of `e.range.getSheet()` is much lower than that of `e.range.getSheet().getName()`. By this, as a sample, in order to retrieve the sheet name of the active sheet, it is required to use the methods of low process cost. In this workaround, as a sample situation, using your provided Spreadsheet, I would like to propose a modified script from your above script.

In this workaround, I use `e.range.getSheet().getSheetId()` instead of `e.range.getSheet().getName()`. And, Sheets API is used. Because the process cost of `e.range.getSheet().getSheetId()` is lower than that of `e.range.getSheet().getName()`, and, in order to retrieve the sheet name from the sheet ID, when the Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp) is used, the process cost becomes high.

When this workaround is reflected in your above script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of your provided Spreadsheet. And, please enable Sheets API. And, please install the OnEdit trigger to the function of `installedOnEdit`. When you use this script, please put a value to a cell. By this, the script works and you can see the sheet name of the active sheet in the log.

```js
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  var t = new Date();
  console.log('we are in onEdit!');
  var sheetId = e.range.getSheet().getSheetId();
  var ssId = e.source.getId();
  const sheetName = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId).sheets.find(s => s.properties.sheetId == sheetId).properties.title;
  console.log(sheetName)
  console.log('We got sheet name. Time past = ' + (new Date() - t));
}
```

- When a value is put to a cell, you can see the sheet name in the log. In my test, the process time was about 3 s.
- In my case, as a workaround like this, when OnEdit trigger and script are used in a Spreadsheet that the large calculations by the formulas are included, I investigate the low-cost methods and use them.

#### Note:

- In this workaround, when the function is executed OnEdit trigger, the formulas are continued to be calculated. So, please be careful about this.

#### Additional information:

As additional information, when I tested this situation, it was found that the cell values are not retrieved, and the process is not affected by the calculation of formulas. When the above sample script is seen, the cell values are not retrieved. It seems that by this, the process cost can be reduced during the calculation of formulas.

On the other hand, when the cell values are put to the cells using Sheets API, it was found that the process is not affected by the calculation of formulas. And also, it was found that when the cell values are put using the Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp), the process is affected by the calculation of formulas.

Comment: thanks @Tanaike! Sheets API may be the way out! I thought that any method will slow down and `getSheetId()` should take as long as `getName()` for the sheet. Will test your solution.

Comment: @Max Makhrov Thank you for replying. At Google Spreadsheet, it seems that when Spreadsheet is retrieved from outside, the effect on the condition of formulas becomes small. For example, when the values are retrieved from a sheet including formulas by Sheets API, the values are retrieved even when the calculation is not finished. I thought that this might be able to be used. So, I used Sheets API.

Comment: @Max Makhrov But, it was found that in your sample Spreadsheet, even when the Spreadsheet service is used, when `getSheetName()` and `getName()` are used, the process cost becomes high. So, I proposed to use Sheets API instead of `openById` and `openByUrl` of Spreadsheet service.

Comment: @Max Makhrov From this situation, although this is my guess, I thought that there might be methods that are run just after the calculations of all formulas were finished in the Spreadsheet service of Google Apps Script.

Comment: thanks again. I've made a test, my sheet is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16cfHAnnrXHDEipLm4sEd0dw0U3tBk67TvnJEB7YcXGI/edit#gid=0. And I confirm it works ~3 sec. and therefore your solution stops script from failure. And also your answer is the only one that shows your interest and engagement in the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Max Makhrov Thank you for replying. As the additional information, in the above-proposed script, the cell values are not retrieved using Sheets API. By this, it is considered that the process is not affected by the calculation of formulas. For example, when the cell values are retrieved, even when Sheets API is used, the process is affected by the calculation of formulas. Please be careful about this.

Comment: @Max Makhrov And, because I thought that this information might be useful for other users, by including more information, I posted this as a report on my blog. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/455ae803fae6a9aba31a928ce5a16c1d) If this was useful, I'm glad.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is wrap your function with a timer to see what is causing the delay.

```
class Timer {
  constructor() {
    this.start = new Date();
  }
  stop() {
    let end = new Date();
    end = (end.valueOf()-this.start.valueOf())/1000;
    console.log("elapsed time: "+end.toFixed(3)+" sec" );
  }
}

function testTimer() {
  try {
    let time = new Timer();
    let a = 0;
    for( let i=0; i<10000; i++ ) {
      a = a+i;
    }
    time.stop();
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

```
5:49:09 AM  Notice  Execution started
5:49:10 AM  Info    elapsed time: 0.001 sec
5:49:10 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

For example in your `onEdit_DVL_(e)`:

```
function onEdit_DVL_(e) {
  let time = new Timer();
  var sets = getConfigDvl0_();
  time.stop();
.
.
.
    time = new Timer();
    sets.sheet = e.range.getSheet();
    sets.sheetName = sets.sheet.getName(); 
    sets.range = e.range,
    sets.value = e.value;
    time.stop();
```

And on any other section of code you think is causing the delay.

Comment: Thanks, did it and got an unexpected result. Generally speaking `range.getName()` took 30+ seconds to run. And this single row of code made my function to time out. This result is unexpected to me as it is caused by formula overload of the file. Why formulas should cause the `range` object to work slow?

Comment: please see the minimal code and file sample here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TjQ2u9u3fqH6296jehNqIn_Q0-MwTU7-K-EsyS26IcU/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays the Google Sheets UI shows a progress bar having a tooltip showing the task being done in the client-side.

1. Loading...
2. Calculating formulas...
3. Loading cells...

Each sheet might show a different progress (bar size and tooltip text).

On my environment when opening your spreadsheet it takes a lot of time (more than a couple of minutes) for the progress bar to disappear and the cell Formulas!H1 shows `#REF` and Error > Import Range Internal Error.

Maybe a change made by Google to the Google Sheets app might affected the spreadsheet performance making not only the Google Apps Script service be slower than what you have experienced in the past but also making at least one formula return an error. You might report this to Google by using the Help > Help Sheets Improve button and/or the official Google Sheets community, or if you are Google Workspace admin by submitting a support ticket. In meantime you could try to reduce the calculation time of your spreadsheet, i.e. by replacing calculations that aren't really needed to be done every time that the spreadsheet is opened and / or on every recalculation by their results by doing a copy paste as values only or by using Google Apps Script in order to have control on when the "calculations" are done.

Another thing that might help is to avoid the use of open references. I.E. your spreadsheet has `=INDEX(VLOOKUP(A:A,{F:F,G:G},2,))` in `Formulas!B1` that is returning a lot of `#N/A` at the bottom of the copy that I made of your spreadsheet. Open references might cause that the spreadsheet have extra blank rows that when there were to many, affect the spreadsheet opening time.

Comment: Thanks @Rubén! You are surely correct! My dummy file has some silly formulas. This was made intentionally to show how it causes bad performance of the script. The unexpected for me was that `SpreadsheetApp` began to slow down when it earlier worked much faster regerdless the formulas. As you've said: 1) I've reported this 2) Reduce formulas -- for my project/client it may be a costly process. This is why I thought better to also report the problem here on Stackoverflow. This bad script performance appeared just this week without any changes to my client's file.

Comment: @MaxMakhrov It's hard to keep track of changes made to shared spreadsheets... are you the only editor ? If not, have you reviewed that the other editors didn't added something that might be causing the problem?